# Replacing characters in a text file with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to replace some characters in a text file with a batch file?

I didn't find any command to do that.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to replace (before and after)?

Comment: I just wanted to replace in a text file all occurences of '<' by an empty character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer is "No, not with basic windows utilities"

But as the other answers suggested, there are lots of unix ports out there that do what you want. Take alook at [gnuwin32 packages](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).

**EDIT:**

Okay, I revise my strict "No". There might be a way of doing it, depending on the complexity of your task and your OS. When using windows 2000 and above, cmd provides command extensions that you can use.

The basic idea is to use a FOR loop to go through each line of an input file and then to use string substitution provided by the SET command to replace your characters.

I have no solution at hand but you might try on your own, using infromation from [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/) quite cool site. Look [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php#FOR_F) for the FOR loop syntax and [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php#StrSubst) for the string substitution.

Comment: The basic problem with iterating over the file is that when it contains special characters such as `&`, `|` or `>` it gets messy. Throw in odd numbers of quotation marks in a line and all bets are off. Haven't found a way to properly escape such characters when there are odd numbers of quotation marks in a line. Otherwise it's easy but messy.

Comment: Oh, just another thing: `for` skips empty lines. If you need the file to survive including those you have to look for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you can install unxutils and then do

```
sed "s/WORD_FROM/WORD_TO/" file_name > changed.file.name
```

to change words
or

```
cat file|tr "a" "b"  > changed.file.name
```

to change characters

Answer (score 1):

Use sed or nothing:

```
sed -i 's/FROM/TO/g' filename.txt
```

sed can be download [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/), for various platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [WIN32 SED](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and see the official gnu sed page for explanation. It is really powerful :

```
> sed "s/WORD_FROM/WORD_TO/" file_name > changed.file.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a command line program like GREP you can call from a batch that will take a replace string and a file and do the swap for you.

Comment: Grep is used to perform search/filter... even wikipedia knows that : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: Indeed, sed is more specific to just that task, but FYI, there are Windows/DOS variants of grep that allow replace as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOS port of Unix command line utility "tr".

A free DOS port can be [found here](http://reimagery.com/fsfd/unix.htm), one of the ones I like (there are many different ones) are "UXUTL — Comprehensive collection of command line Unix utilities for DOS."

The benefit is that you get a WHOLE BUNCh of incredibly useful commands, not just tr.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is quite old, future reader may be interested to know that if you want a small exe with no dependencies for just replacing text I recommend using [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/).