# Remove / in text file with using DOS script

Tags: dos

I want to create .bat application that read into text file, find / and remove it.

FROM PPD/HQ
ALLEN/BRAD/MR

change to:-

FROM PPD HQ
ALLEN BRAD MR

Eliminate the / and save in other text file will be just fine.

I'm a newbie and help me to enter DOS world.

Thnx!

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504070/replacing-characters-in-a-text-file-with-a-dos-batch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this really have to be pure MS-DOS?  As in, no Windows, no extra tools?  If you mean a "DOS Box" -- really, a Windows console -- and are able to install [a little software](http://cygwin.com/) to help you, this one-liner will do it:

```
$ tr / ' ' < original-file.txt > new-file.txt
```

That's [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) shell syntax calling the POSIX `tr` program, rather than an MS-DOS style batch program.  The Unixy command line offered by Cygwin is vastly more powerful than the legacy MS-DOS stuff, even with the minor enhancements Microsoft has added over the years.

Plus, it's a gateway into the Linux/BSD/OS X/Unix world, another fun place to play.