# change string in txt file

Tags: string, batch-file

Is it possible using a batch script to change string in a txt file?

For example, I have `status.txt`, which contains 2 lines:

```
SingleSite integer1
MultiSite  integer2
```

I want to change them into:

```
TAG  integer1
Engineer integer2
```

so `SingleSite` becomes `TAG` and `MultiSite` becomes `Engineer`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing characters in a text file with a dos-batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504070/replacing-characters-in-a-text-file-with-a-dos-batch)

Comment: @Helen I don't think it's exactly the same, it's character versus string replacement. It's possibly the same on Windows (I'm not particularly familiar with it), but e.g. on Linux it would be using `tr` versus using `sed`

Comment: @Michael You are of course correct, but there are several links to various `sed`s in that post.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e "s/SingleSite/TAG/g" status.txt > new.status.txt` using one of the ports of sed mentioned in the article in Helen's comment.